Reweight Pandas column after resetting values based on nan's in another column
PyNoob here.  Given dataframe such as:
df = pd.DataFrame({'Type': ['A', np.nan, 'B', 'C', 'D', np.nan], 'wgt': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.25, 0.1, 0.05]})

I would like to set the wgts = 0 for Type = nan, and reweight the wgts so they still to sum to same value (1 in this ex.).  I can achieve this in several steps; i.e. get sum(wgts), get sum(nan_wgts), set wgts to 0 where Type is nan, then new_wgts = wgts * (1 + (sum(nan_wgts)/sum(wgts))).
The result should be:
'new_wgt' = ~ [0.1333, 0, 0.4, 0.3333, 0.1333, 0]
Surely, there is a much simpler and efficient way to do this than I am.  Thanks

mask the numbers for which the matching Type isna, then divide by the sum:
s = df['wgt'].mask(df['Type'].isna(), 0)
df['new_wgt'] = s.div(s.sum())

As a one-liner:
df['new_wgt'] = df['wgt'].mask(df['Type'].isna(), 0).pipe(lambda x: x/x.sum())

Output:
  Type   wgt   new_wgt
0    A  0.10  0.133333
1  NaN  0.20  0.000000
2    B  0.30  0.400000
3    C  0.25  0.333333
4    D  0.10  0.133333
5  NaN  0.05  0.000000

